# Get Facebook third_party_id from uid in Javascript

Tags: facebook

Does anyone how to get the third_party_id from 'uid' in Javascript?

I'm trying to look for it but no success.

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`third_party_id` is a field on the [User object in the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) but it's not a default field - it will only be returned if you specifically request it, e.g.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=third_party_id&access_token=[YOUR ACCESS TOKEN]
```

will return:

```
{
  "third_party_id": "[THIRD PARTY ID]", 
  "id": "[USER ID]", 
  "type": "user"
}
```

In javascript, you most likely want to call

```
FB.api("/me?fields=third_party_id", function (userData) { 
    alert("Your Facebook ThirdPartyId is: " + userData["third_party_id"]);
});
```